# ie9 post request losing query parameters

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, express, internet-explorer-9

I'm writing an application that, unfortunately, still has IE9 support. my requirement has another application posting data and redirecting (via a form POST) into my application, along with query parameters. I'm using Node and express to parse the query params and render a page. I'm running into an issue where, if there are query parameters on a post request, IE9 is actually making three requests, one POST with data, one GET with query params, and one GET without anything attached at all. This seems to effect only IE9, any suggestions on how to make it happen like all other browsers, in one request?

EDIT: now with code

```
<form action="/testPath/?path=placetoGo&group-id=281740360804&ref-id=2817403600034&itineraryTypeCode=RT&type=edd&num-adults=1" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value='something'>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

so that's the request to the node/express server.

on the server, IE9 comes in with three requests, first one is a POST with the object on the body. the second is a GET with the query params, and the third is a GET without the post data or query params.

Comment: Please post your code and show the requests which are made.  It is hard to answer your question otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

Did You try to change the type attribute of the `submit button` from `submit` to `button` since you post with `javascript`
also change

```
<form action="/testPath/?path=placetoGo&group-id=281740360804&ref-id=2817403600034&itineraryTypeCode=RT&type=edd&num-adults=1" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="/testPath/placetoGo&281740360804&2817403600034&RT&edd&1" method="POST">
```